# Deploy EAR has origin WAR and copied WAR on wildfly 9

Tags: java, spring, wildfly

I have to deploy one EAR that contain two WAR, One WAR is copy of another WAR.

- BUILD.ear
- A.war (context path : /A)
- B.war (context path : /B)

I had test it on my local machine using eclipse debug mode, but some understandable situation are found.

step 1. request to `localhost:8080/A/someURL`

step 2. caught break point of controller in A.war

step 3. caught break point of service in B.war

Why debugger caught break point in not A.war but B.war despite I had requested context path /a? Had Spring container ignore duplicate scanned class?

Comment: This site does have a tag system. There's no point adding hashtags as well.

Comment: what do you mean by "breakpoint in B.war"? a breakpoint is on a source code line, maybe it is just eclipse having trouble attaching the right source code from the data received by the jvm

Comment: sorry. "caught breakpoint of service in B.war" mean that requested controller is in A.war, but program flow to business logic in B.war. although there is no dependency between A.war and B.war. B.war is just copy of A.war

Answer (score 0):

AFIK all WARs from one EAR will be loaded using the same class loader. If both A.WAR and B.WAR contains the same classes ... you probably do not really want this to happen and need to re-organize your WARs.